# How can I solve "horseshoe effect" on ordination analysis (Canonical Correspondence Analysis)?

Tags: r, correspondence-analysis

I would like to ask for help in the analysis of Canonical Correspondence Analysis (CCA) that I did in the Vegan package in R, with my dataset of species and environmental parameters. The result appears in the image below. The expressed result shows the "horseshoe effect". I have already researched the subject in *[Numerical Ecology with R](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3319714031)* and other books and papers, and I found some explanations that talk about metric distance saturation (Morton et al, 2017 - [Uncovering the Horseshoe Effect in Microbial Analyses](https://msystems.asm.org/content/2/1/e00166-16)). What sort of ordination analysis should I do instead of CCA so that I don't have the horseshoe effect again, and how can I solve the metrics issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The classical way of addressing the horseshoe effect in CA is by Detrended CA (see e.g. [Here](https://rdrr.io/rforge/vegan/man/decorana.html)), although I find this a bit far fetched.

Alternatively, model-based ordinations are available for constrained ordination of count data (which I assume you have), e.g. the RC(M) method for which the *RCM* package is available in R (yes I am the author).